# Woocommerce Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_stock_quantity() on null in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, methods, product

I have received a message from WordPress about a fatal error. It came after placing the following code in functions.php to change # in stock message to # custom message

###### The Code I used:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  global $product;
  $stock = $product->get_total_stock();

  if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __($stock . ' Tickets Left', 'woocommerce');
  if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('SOLD OUT', 'woocommerce');

  return $availability;
}
```

###### The error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_total_stock() on null
>
> ```
> An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 253 of the file /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php.
> Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_total_stock() on null in /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:253
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): custom_get_availability()
> #1 /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #2 /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(2101): apply_filters()
> #3 /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(3572): WC_Product->get_availability()
> #4 /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php(367): wc_get_stock_html()
> #5 /home/1012316.cloudwaysapps.com/ajfcdvpgsd/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php(312 [...]
> ```

Comment: `$product` is not an instance of Product. Maybe it's value is `null`. Why don't you use `$_product` when passed instead?

Comment: You don't need `global $product;`, so remove it, as the function has already `$_product` argument that you can use. Use instead `$stock = $_product->get_total_stock();`